# How to write "WHERE foo = 'bar' OR foo = 'baz' OR ..." without repeating "foo" each time

Tags: sql, mysql, where-clause

I'm new to MySQL and was wondering; instead of doing

```
SELECT fields FROM table WHERE name="tim" OR name="bob" OR name="nancy" OR name="john"
```

If I could do something like

```
SELECT fields FROM table WHERE (name="tim" OR "bob" OR "nancy" OR "john")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `IN` clause:

```
SELECT fields FROM table WHERE name IN ("tim", "bob", "nancy", "john");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do like -

```
SELECT fields FROM table WHERE name in("tim","bob","nancy","john")
```